# I keep getting a "Swift Dynamic Cast Failed". How do I fix it?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am trying to follow a tutorial and create a Tic Tac Toe app, but I get an error, "Swift Dynamic Cast Failed".

My code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{    
    var activePlayer = 1
    var gameActive = true
    //1 - Circle, 2 = Cross

    var gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    var winningCombinations = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6]]

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var gameOverLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func gameOverPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
         activePlayer = 1
         gameActive = true
        //1 - Circle, 2 = Cross
        gameState = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

        var abutton: UIButton

        for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {
            abutton = view.viewWithTag(i) as UIButton!
            abutton.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)


            }

        gameOverLabel.hidden = true
        gameOverButton.hidden = true
        gameOverLabel.center = CGPointMake(gameOverLabel.center.x - 4000, gameOverLabel.center.y)
        gameOverButton.center = CGPointMake(gameOverButton.center.x - 4000, gameOverButton.center.y)

           }
    @IBOutlet weak var gameOverButton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if gameState[sender.tag] == 0 && gameActive == true{

        var image = UIImage()

        gameState[sender.tag] = activePlayer
        if activePlayer == 1{
           image = UIImage(named: "circle.png")!
            sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
            activePlayer = 2
        }else if activePlayer == 2{
          image = UIImage(named: "cross.png")!
            sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
            activePlayer = 1

        }
         sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

            for combination in winningCombinations {


                if gameState[combination[0]] != 0 && gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]{
                     var labelText = "Compiler has won"
                    if gameState[combination[0]] == 1{
                       labelText = "Programmer has Won"
                    }
                    gameOverLabel.hidden = false
                    gameOverButton.hidden = false

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

                        self.gameOverLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.gameOverLabel.center.x + 4000, self.gameOverLabel.center.y)
                        self.gameOverButton.center = CGPointMake(self.gameOverButton.center.x + 4000, self.gameOverButton.center.y)

                    })
                    gameActive = false

            }


            }




      }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        gameOverLabel.hidden = true
        gameOverButton.hidden = true
        gameOverLabel.center = CGPointMake(gameOverLabel.center.x - 4000, gameOverLabel.center.y)
        gameOverButton.center = CGPointMake(gameOverButton.center.x - 4000, gameOverButton.center.y)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    }
}
```

and the error that I get when I attempt to run this program is:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x10860f620:  pushq  %rbp
0x10860f621:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10860f624:  pushq  %rbx
0x10860f625:  pushq  %rax
0x10860f626:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x10860f629:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x10860f62c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x10860f62e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x10860f631:  je     0x10860f64c               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 44
0x10860f633:  movq   0x82756(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x10860f63a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x10860f63d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x10860f640:  callq  0x1086121ca               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x10860f645:  testb  %al, %al
0x10860f647:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x10860f64a:  je     0x10860f653               ; swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x10860f64c:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x10860f650:  popq   %rbx
0x10860f651:  popq   %rbp
0x10860f652:  retq   
0x10860f653:  leaq   0xcdc8(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10860f65a:  movq   %rax, 0x8ae57(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10860f661:  int3   
0x10860f662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

I am new to programming so I would appreciate simple answers. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that all of the views with tag 0-9 are UIButtons? It seems unlikely as the default tag is 0 for any view.

```
 for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {
        abutton = view.viewWithTag(i) as UIButton!
        abutton.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
        }
```

I imagine it is grabbing a UIView or some other view on your storyboard and trying to cast it to a UIButton and then crashing.

Comment: Thanks, I was accidentally using UIView with tag 0